# MySQL: Order results by multiple columns

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have the following table 'products':

```
+----+------------+------------+----------+------+
| ID | Name       | Purchased  | Promoted | Used |
+----+------------+------------+----------+------+
| 0  | TV         | 2017-10-02 | 0        | 0    |
| 1  | Radio      | 2017-08-27 | 1        | 0    |
| 2  | Fridge     | 2017-09-03 | 1        | 1    |
| 3  | Dishwasher | 2017-08-15 | 0        | 1    |
| 4  | Bike       | 2017-09-17 | 0        | 1    |
| 5  | Computer   | 2017-10-03 | 0        | 0    |
+----+------------+------------+----------+------+
```

Now I want to fetch all records in the following order:

1. rows with 'Promoted=1' ordered by column 'Purchased'
2. rows with 'Used=1' ordered by column 'Purchased'
3. remaining rows ordered by column 'Purchased'

Result:

```
+---+------------+------------+---+---+
| 2 | Fridge     | 2017-09-03 | 1 | 1 |
+---+------------+------------+---+---+
| 1 | Radio      | 2017-08-27 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | Bike       | 2017-09-17 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | Dishwasher | 2017-08-15 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | Computer   | 2017-10-03 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | TV         | 2017-10-02 | 0 | 0 |
+---+------------+------------+---+---+
```

What would be the MySQL query ?

Comment: I can't see your attempt ?!!?

Answer (score 0):

As easy as it will seem :

```
ORDER BY Promoted = 1 DESC,
         Used = 1 DESC,
         Purchased DESC
```

MySQL evaluate Boolean expression as 1 and 0 .

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT  * FROM PRODUCTS  ORDER BY PRODUCT.PROMOTED DESC, PRODUCT.USED DESC`

Answer (score -1):

You could use a UNION statement like

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE Promoted='1' ORDER BY Purchased 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM products WHERE Promoted!='1' AND Used='1' ORDER BY Purchased
UNION 
SELECT * FROM products WHERE Promoted!='1' AND Used!='1' ORDER BY Purchased
```